# Authentication failed : Facebook, google plus login with hybridauth showing code 5 with redirect URL

Tags: facebook, google-plus, hybridauth, question2answer

I am using Hybridauth plugin[q2a-open-login-master] for my question2answer platform site. It works on my previous host and I migrated the pack into new host. So I created new Facebook application and new Google project with that new redirect URL.

Both Facebook and Google-plus login never working now.

Facebook login almost working But in the redirection to my site, Suddenly showing code=5. And checked in error-log file. There showing

```
 Invalid IPv6 configuration on server, Please disable or get native IPv6 on your server.
```

And also Google-plus login asking the permission window as offline access. But before that no asking such offline access. And then showing an error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: adapter in /home/example/public_html/qa-plugin/q2a-open-login-master/qa-open-login.php on line 119

Fatal error: Call to a member function logout() on a non-object in /home/example/public_html/qa-plugin/q2a-open-login-master/qa-open-login.php on line 119
```

How can I fix this issues? I did not get the exact reason for this issues.

Comment: any help please now its showing this error message "
Notice: Undefined variable: adapter in /home/neoliluv/public_html/qa-plugin/q2a-open-login-master/qa-open-login.php on line 119

Fatal error: Call to a member function logout() on a non-object in /home/neoliluv/public_html/qa-plugin/q2a-open-login-master/qa-open-login.php on line 119" when try to login with google-plus. Please help

Comment: I am seeing this error to on the lastest `master`